# How to check through node.js if a web page has JS variable defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Node.js app is given a link to a page and needs to check if certain JS variable is defined.

eg: the said app is given "http://jquery.com" and it should return a boolean if `$` is defined as global variable.

How do I do this?

EDIT: shorter question, hopefully clearer

Comment: *"Can I avoid using phantom.js to check the existence of a global var?"* Of course, just use *any other* browser. Why don't you want to use PhantomJS?

Comment: @ArtjomB. sorry, should have made it clearer: can I avoid using any "browser-js" (seems a bit expensive just to check if var is defined)

Comment: Yes, you can for example get the page source then get each JS resource in order to `eval()` it in node.js, but since node.js has a completely different execution environment than every browser, this won't work reliably. Just use a (headless) browser.

Answer (score 1):

To make an http request in node, you can load the http module which comes standard.  More about node http [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback)

```
var http = require('http');
```

since GET requests are so common, there is a method specifically for them,

```
http.get(url, (req, res) => {
    // res object contains the response.
    // you'll need to parse the html for script tags here
});
```

you'd then have to parse the DOM, looking for script tags or links to script tags.  If you know of a package that already does this, it would probably be much easier.